# How secure is Derby DB?

Tags: database, security, derby

I just started with Derby DB yesterday. I have a small concern that when i connect to a Derby Db, i dont have to specify any username and password, unlike MySQL server and the stuff. So isn't it possible for some other person who knows my database name to access it without any privillege?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Derby DB doesn't require authentication by default. But it is possible to set it up if required.

[Additional info here..](http://db.apache.org/derby/binaries/jta-WE15.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to authentication, Derby also supports authorization, disk encryption, network encryption, etc. There are a lot of security features in Derby. You'll want to spend some time studying http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.8/devguide/devguide-single.html#cdevcsecuree